# jquery how to add image in table TD near specified text

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, image

I have a php scripts which shows data from worldoftanks api server. I show this data in table so I would like to add image near every user whos rank is "Recruit".

This is my javascript for table:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "clan_info.php",
                            success: function(data){
                                var htmlString = '<table cellpadding="0px" class="menu1"><tr><th>Username</th><th>Rank</th><th>PR</th><th>BTL</th><th>W/B</th><th>E/B</th><th>Days</th></tr>';
                                var clanData = JSON.parse(data);
                                i = 0;
                                for(userID in clanData){
                                    userData = clanData[userID];
                                    var extraClass = '';
                                    if(i < 3) {
                                        extraClass = 'class="rank' + (i+1) + '"';
                                    }
                                    htmlString += '<tr>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['name'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['role'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['rating'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['battles'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['w_p_b'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['xp_p_b'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['days'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '</tr>';
                                    i++;
                                }
                                htmlString += '</table>';
                                console.log(htmlString);
                                $("#wot").html(htmlString);
                            }

                        });
                    });

                </script>
```

AND MY PHP SCRIPT:

```html
<?php
$clanID = "500006494";
$clanApiPage = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wgn/clans/info/?application_id=demo&clan_id=$clanID";
$userApiPage = "https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/info/?application_id=demo&account_id=";
$clanStrongHoldPage = "https://developers.wargaming.net/reference/all/wot/stronghold/info?application_id=demo&clan_id=$clanID";

$getAndDecode = function($url) {
 $jsonData = file_get_contents($url);   
 $dataArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);
 return $dataArray;
};
$determineDays = function($date) {
 $datediff = time() - $date;
 return floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
};
$jsonData = $getAndDecode($clanApiPage) , ($clanStrongHoldPage);
$clanAccounts = array();
foreach($jsonData["data"][$clanID]["members"] as $memberArray) {
 $accountID = $memberArray["account_id"];
 $clanAccounts[$accountID]['id'] = $memberArray["account_id"];
 $clanAccounts[$accountID]['role'] = $memberArray["role_i18n"];
 $clanAccounts[$accountID]['name'] = $memberArray["account_name"];
 $clanAccounts[$accountID]['days'] = $determineDays($memberArray["joined_at"]);
}
$accountIDs = implode(",", array_keys($clanAccounts));
$apiPage = $userApiPage . $accountIDs;
$userJsonData = $getAndDecode($apiPage);
foreach($userJsonData["data"] as $userID => $dataArray) {
 $playerStatistic = $dataArray["statistics"]["all"];
 $clanAccounts[$userID]['rating'] = $dataArray["global_rating"];
 $clanAccounts[$userID]['battles'] = $playerStatistic["battles"];
 $clanAccounts[$userID]['w_p_b'] = $playerStatistic["wins"]/$playerStatistic["battles"] * 100;//wins per battle
 $clanAccounts[$userID]['xp_p_b'] = $playerStatistic["battle_avg_xp"]; //experience per battle
}
$w_p_b = array();
foreach ($clanAccounts as $userID => $row) {
 $w_p_b[$userID] = $row['w_p_b'];
}
array_multisort($w_p_b, SORT_DESC, $clanAccounts);
die(json_encode($clanAccounts));
?>
```

my table sample here: http://www.slovenian-army.tk/members.html

I would like to put image near every user like this:
[sloa_clan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i4KW.png)

Depends on what rank is user. If user is Comander he gets comanders icon
If user is Recruit he gets Recruit icon.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question, at least specify in more detail. Or read the rules, how to ask a good question. http://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0):

I find out how to do this.
by adding this var:

```
var username = '<img src="images/'  + userData['role'] + '.png" height="25" width="25"   />' + userData['name'];
```

and code now looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "clan_info.php",
                            success: function(data){
                                var htmlString = '<table cellpadding="0px" class="menu1"><tr><th>Username</th><th>Rank</th><th>PR</th><th>BTL</th><th>W/B</th><th>E/B</th><th>Days</th></tr>';
                                var clanData = JSON.parse(data);
                                i = 0;
                                for(userID in clanData){
                                    userData = clanData[userID];
                                    var extraClass = '';
                                    if(i < 3) {
                                        extraClass = 'class="rank' + (i+1) + '"';
                                    }
                                    var username = '<img src="images/'  + userData['role'] + '.png" height="25" width="25"   />' + userData['name'];
                                    htmlString += '<tr>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + username + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['role'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['rating'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['battles'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['w_p_b'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['xp_p_b'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '<td '+extraClass+'><a href="http://worldoftanks.eu/en/community/accounts/' + userData['id'] +'" target="_blank">' + userData['days'] + '</a></td>';
                                    htmlString += '</tr>';
                                    i++;
                                }
                                htmlString += '</table>';
                                console.log(htmlString);
                                $("#wot").html(htmlString);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
```